# Comparing strings of numbers with strings of words of numbers

Tags: python

I have two strings. One contains digits the other contains words. I cannot predict which one's which nor the size of the number.

```
S1  = "thirteen things that don't make sense"
S2 = "13 Things That Don't Make Sense"
```

obviously

```
S1 != S2
```

what is the best way to test in python that the two strings contain the same information?

Comment: Are you trying to test if they have the same information?  I'm pretty sure they do have information. :-)

Comment: DIgits could be in which range? 0 to ?

Comment: i am uncertain as to what you want, do you want a way to compare them as if the digits (13) and the letters (thirteen) are the same? or do you want to simply check if they are not the same.. which is very simple `print (S1 == S2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mapping of strings that should be considered equivalent to some other string, and then convert each sentence to remove case differences and replace words using the mapping before comparing, for example:

```
S1 = "thirteen things that don't make sense"
S2 = "13 Things That Don't Make Sense"
eq_map = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'thirteen': '13'}

def convert(s):
    s = s.lower()
    return [eq_map.get(w, w) for w in s.split()]

assert convert(S1) == convert(S2)
```

The difficult part here comes from creating a comprehensive `eq_map`, the module that [CosmicComputer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763961/505154) may be useful.

You may also want to do something here to remove punctuation, you could accomplish this by adding something like `s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', s)` to `convert()`.

Comment: great idea, but i fear that perhaps it will trade the "1" in "13" into "one" and the "3" into "three" and then you will not get "13" into "thirteen" ??

Comment: nevermind, i see that this will not happen, since it only converts from letters to numbers....  well written and very elegant.

Comment: @InbarRose - Even if it converted from numbers to letters it wouldn't cause an issue, because before performing the substitution the sentence is split on whitespace and then entire words are substituted.

Answer (score 1):

This module might be able to help you out:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pynum2word/

Comment: Does that project have documentation anywhere?